# Проблема с синтаксисом на Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

На постгри только начала работать. Борюсь с синтаксисом. Пишу запрос ниже

```
DO $$
declare 
        v_class_code varchar(12);
        v_class_name varchar(128);
        v_firms_id  varchar(12) ;
        v_right_flags int ;
begin
    update quik.classes 
    set class_name = 'Test'
    where id = 1
    returning class_code, class_name, firms_id, right_flags into v_class_code, v_class_name, v_firms_id, v_right_flags;

     select v_class_code, v_class_name, v_firms_id, v_right_flags
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Выдается ошибка ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 15: $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 376

Что не так?

Comment: Я погуглил, вроде `LANGUAGE` нужно сразу после `DO` писать, до основного кода. Если его вообще нужно писать. То есть `DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$ ... end;$$` вроде как. Ну либо попробуйте вообще выкинуть `LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

Comment: Так тоже не работает.

Comment: `select v_class_code, v_class_name, v_firms_id, v_right_flags` запрос-то допишите, где остальная часть запроса? Парсер дошёл до конца $$ и не понимает, что вы хотели сказать и что от него хотите дальше.

Comment: В итоге сработало вместо селекта: raise notice '% % % %', v_class_code, v_class_name, v_firms_id, v_right_flags;

Answer (score 2):

1. Язык обычно указывается в начале, а не в конце. Анонимный блок - это не процедура. Впрочем, так можно, это не ошибка.
2. Зачем нужны переменные и RETURNING, если результат нигде не будет использован?
3. То же самое - о финальном недописанном SELECT. Да и в принципе SELECT в выходной поток в анонимном блоке - не бывает.

```
CREATE TABLE classes (
  class_code  VARCHAR(12),
  class_name VARCHAR(128),
  firms_id VARCHAR(12),
  right_flags INT,
  id INT
);
INSERT INTO classes VALUES
('code 1', 'class name 1', 'firm 1', 1, 1),
('code 2', 'class name 2', 'firm 2', 2, 2),
('code 3', 'class name 3', 'firm 3', 3, 3);
```

```
DO $$
/*
  declare 
        v_class_code varchar(12);
        v_class_name varchar(128);
        v_firms_id  varchar(12) ;
        v_right_flags int ;
  */
begin
   update classes 
   set class_name = 'Test'
   where id = 1
/*   returning class_code, class_name, firms_id, right_flags into v_class_code, v_class_name, v_firms_id, v_right_flags */ ;

--   select v_class_code, v_class_name, v_firms_id, v_right_flags
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
SELECT * FROM classes;
```

| class_code | class_name | firms_id | right_flags | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| code 2 | class name 2 | firm 2 | 2 | 2 |
| code 3 | class name 3 | firm 3 | 3 | 3 |
| code 1 | Test | firm 1 | 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/50olhO9X)

Comment: Мне надо понять, что возвращают именно переменные. Поэтому просто вывод на экран.

Comment: @DHel Либо используй переменные, определённые извне процедуры, либо сливай результат во временную таблицу и потом вычитывай оттуда. Документация чётко указывает: *The code block is treated as though it were the body of **a function with no parameters, returning void**.* Вот именно так к ней и следует относиться. С другой стороны - кто мешает прочитать прямо из таблицы изменённую запись? WHERE-то ты знаешь...